# Set value of a HubSpot hidden form field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I've got a small bit of Javascript code in the head of the website:

```
<!-- Unique form ID -->
<script>
   document.querySelector('input[name=form_submission_id]').value = new Date();
</script>
```

My goal is to get a hidden form field with the name 'form submission id' to populate with a date stamp, but I keep getting the error - Cannot set property 'value' of null

If I go into inspector tools and unhide the hidden form field the above code works, if it's hidden I get the error.

Here's a link to the live form: https://easytrimreveals.com/samples/

I'm assuming it's the form loading after the script has already fired but I'm not sure how to resolve that if that's the case.

I tried creating a timeout delay for the script to fire but that didn't seem to work either..

```
<script>

  var formId = function() {
      document.querySelector('input[name=form_submission_id]').value = new Date();
  }
  document.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(formId, 3000);
}

</script>
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  document.querySelector('input[name="form_submission_id"]').value = new Date();
});`

Comment: Tried that, just got the same error.  Cannot set property 'value' of null.

Comment: Take care about `'input[name="form_submission_id"]'`

Comment: I put the quotes in, same error..

Comment: It seems like you are using a Hubspot form served inside an iframe. I'm not too familiar with Hubspot but I think you might have to make your changes in one of the events provided by Hubspot (most probably on the [onFormSubmit](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/global-form-events) event).

Comment: That seems feasible. I'm just not sure where to access that JavaScript code.. Admittedly I'm not a developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up getting help from a friend and it's solved!

Thanks for all your help!

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
   if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormReady') {
    document.getElementById("hs-form-iframe-0").contentDocument.querySelector('input[name="form_submission_id"]').value = new Date();
   }
});
</script>
```